# Which file is this line of code looking for

Tags: node.js, canvas, webpack

I am new to working with node packages. I am trying to add canvas to my project. However I am seeing this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/canvas/lib/bindings.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/canvas' in      'C:\Users\me\myapp\node_modules\canvas\lib'
@ ./~/canvas/lib/bindings.js 3:17-51
@ ./~/canvas/lib/canvas.js
@ ./app/app.js
@ ./app/components/base/base.spec.js
```

I look in the bindings.js file and the only code is:

```
module.exports = require('../build/Release/canvas');
```

I navigate to the ../build/Release/canvas folder and find 5 files named canvas with different extensions:

```
canvas.exp
canvas.lib
canvas.map
canvas.node
canvas.pdb
```

Is the require code looking for any of these files? What is causing the 'Can't resolve' error?

Comment: it's looking for `canvas.js`

Comment: How did you add canvas to your project ? Did you try with npm install ? Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Comment: See here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html It is looking for Release/canvas.js/ or Release/canvas/index.js

Comment: kazu, I did use npm install as indicated on the web page. However, I needed to follow the steps here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/619 to get npm install canvas to "work" without errors. Is the problem that npm install canvas isn't working correctly?

Comment: Oh well, never had such an issue before. Did you get any message telling you canvas installation was successful with that link ? If yes, the problem might be that the files were put in the wrong place. It's weird that you don't have a canvas.js in the /build/Release/canvas/ in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = require('../build/Release/canvas');
```

this require will look for (depend of node configuration):
- canvas.js
- canvas.ts
- index.js 
- index.ts

required file should have js moduloe structure

Comment: It will look for .../Release/canvas.js or .../Release/canvas/index.js, not index.js (BTW, node by default will never look for a .ts file)

Comment: As I mentioned, it depends on configuration